# Htaccess Redirection 301 FROM "with parameter" to "without parameter"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For .htaccess file, I am creating a 301 redirection for my new website:

**I want this:**

> From http://www.website.com/php_file.php?target=value1 to
>   http://www.website.com/NewPage/

**AND**

> From http://www.website.com/php_file.php?target=value2 to
>   http://www.website.com/OtherNewPage/

**i was trying**

```
Redirect 301 /php_file.php?target=value1 http://www.website.com/newpage/
```

But I'm getting this result:

> http://www.website.com/?target=value1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this instead:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^target=value1$
RewriteRule ^php_file.php$ http://www.website.com/newpage/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^target=value2$
RewriteRule ^php_file.php$ http://www.website.com/OtherNewPage/? [R=301,L]
```

The Key here is to use `?` at the end of your redirection to prevent old query string to be added.